# Django ORM get record with latest date

Tags: django, django-orm

This is the data I have:

```python
class RdpUserPasswordHash(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='password_hash')
    when = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
```

```sql
select id, "when", user_id from registry_rdpuserpasswordhash where user_id =3;
```

```
1 2023-07-29 10:55:41.193 +0200  3
2 2022-08-09 10:55:41.236 +0200  3
```

I need to filter getting for each user_id the latest record wrt "when" and I do not find a reliable way to do it with the ORM.

(1)

```python
for r in RdpUserPasswordHash.objects.order_by('user_id', '-when').distinct('user_id'):
    if r.user_id==3:
        print(r)
<RdpUserPasswordHash: RdpUserPasswordHash object (1)>
```

RdpUserPasswordHash object (1) is the one with the latest date

(2)

```python
RdpUserPasswordHash.objects.order_by('user_id', '-when').distinct('user_id').filter(when__lt=timezone.now() - td_expire_days)
<QuerySet [<RdpUserPasswordHash: RdpUserPasswordHash object (2)>]>
```

But I need to now, among the ones with the latest date which one is expired but with the above query I get the unexpected result. Unexpected because it is not in `RdpUserPasswordHash.objects.order_by('user_id', '-when').distinct('user_id')`
So adding a filter actually changes the result of the initial queryset.

QUERIES generated by the ORM:

(1)

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("registry_rdpuserpasswordhash"."user_id") "registry_rdpuserpasswordhash"."id", "registry_rdpuserpasswordhash"."user_id", "registry_rdpuserpasswordhash"."password_hash", "registry_rdpuserpasswordhash"."when" FROM "registry_rdpuserpasswordhash" INNER JOIN "registry_rdpuser" ON ("registry_rdpuserpasswordhash"."user_id" = "registry_rdpuser"."id") WHERE ("registry_rdpuser"."is_active" AND "registry_rdpuserpasswordhash"."when" < '2023-07-28T08:23:32.599017+00:00'::timestamptz) ORDER BY "registry_rdpuserpasswordhash"."user_id" ASC, "registry_rdpuserpasswordhash"."when" DESC LIMIT 21
```

(2)

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("registry_rdpuserpasswordhash"."user_id") "registry_rdpuserpasswordhash"."id", "registry_rdpuserpasswordhash"."user_id", "registry_rdpuserpasswordhash"."password_hash", "registry_rdpuserpasswordhash"."when" FROM "registry_rdpuserpasswordhash" INNER JOIN "registry_rdpuser" ON ("registry_rdpuserpasswordhash"."user_id" = "registry_rdpuser"."id") WHERE ("registry_rdpuser"."is_active" AND "registry_rdpuserpasswordhash"."when" < '2023-07-28T08:23:32.599017+00:00'::timestamptz) ORDER BY "registry_rdpuserpasswordhash"."user_id" ASC, "registry_rdpuserpasswordhash"."when" DESC LIMIT 21
```

My current workaround is:

```python
expired_users = RdpUserPasswordHash.objects.values('user_id').annotate(latest_date=Max('when')).filter(latest_date__lt=timezone.now() - td_expire_days)
```

which yields an empty query set as expected with the data currently in my table (td_expire_days=90). Since I need the RdpUserPasswordHash instances the I will need to loop through the queryset and make queries to get them, something like:

```python
for ep in expired_users:
   ruph = RdpUserPasswordHash.objects.get(user_id=ep['user_id'], when=ep['latest_date'])
   ....
```

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: I use postgresql

Comment: I'm not really following what you want to achieve. So something is expired in 90 days, so you want to find the `RdpUserPasswordHash` who are expired?

Comment: RdpUserPasswordHash stores a hash of each password the user has used so that I can check that he is not using the same one.
I need to force them to change it in say 90 days from the last change so I need to filter on the latest timestamp for each distinct user

Comment: so you basically want to retrieve the users for which there exists no `RdpUserPasswordHash` in the last 90 days? It is perhaps better to ask *what* you want and less *how* you want to do that, this is the well known X/Y problem :)

Comment: Yes, I think you're right

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the `User`s for which there is no `RdpUserPasswordHash` for the last 90 days with:

```
from datetime import timedelta

from django.utils.timezone import now

User.objects.exclude(password_hash__when__gte=now() - timedelta(days=90))
```